# Show new frame with qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, window

I need to open a new QMainWindow when i click on a button.I would understand why it works with a pointer and does not work with a reference :

the slot that fires a new window is the following ,it should open two window but only the window created with the new operator shows up:

```
MyWin win1(this);
win1.show();
MyWin *win2 = new MyWin(this);
win2->show();
```

the following are MyWin.h and MyWin.ccp

```
#ifndef MyWin_H
#define MyWin_H
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class FrmManipolo1;
}


Class MyWin : public QMainWindow
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyWin(QMainWindow *parent = 0);
    ~MyWin();

    private:
    Ui::MyWin *ui;
};

#endif
```

MyWin.cpp

```
include "MyWin.h"
include "ui_MyWin.h"

MyWin::MyWin(QMainWindow *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MyWin)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MyWin::~MyWin()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: So you are trying to open a window which you didn't create/instantiate (`new`) and you wonder why ? By the way a pointer *is* a reference.

Comment: And why i don't get a null pointer exception?I thought that with the first notation an object would be created automatically.So no object has been created with MyWin win1(this);?I thought that both methods should work,but with the first one the object is put in the stack,with the latter in the heap

Comment: It is created, but it is destroyed when the `win1` variable goes out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work:

```
MyWin win1(this);
win1.show();
```

because it creates the `win1` object on the stack, so the `win1` object is destroyed at the end of the current scope, before it can actually be drawn.

This works:

```
MyWin *win2 = new MyWin(this);
win2->show();
```

because the object is allocated on the heap and it's lifetime doesn't end at the current scope, it ends when you call delete on it's address (the `win2` pointer, that only holds the address of the object, not the actual object), or the parent will call delete in your case (because you pass the `this` pointer as a parent parameter to the constructor).